# Report viewer problem with II7

Tags: iis-7.5

I am unable to load reports in a web application deployed on  IIS 7 .

Comment: really? Do you want to tell us some details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add handler in IIS7 manager for report viewer.

see this link (solution with snapshots)

http://www.techipost.com/how-solve-report-viewer-issue-in-iis-7-and-higher-versions/

Comment: No i am asking a question that i am unable to load report viewer in my application and it has been deployed on IIS 7. any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a report viewer control? Make sure that the report server url and report path are right. The report server url usually has the word ReportServer on it. I personally did not have to change or add a handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104.aspx